# I am Making a Discord bot using jda

Tags: java, discord-jda

I wanna add a function to get cat images could someone in here get me the code plz !!!

I have tried using

```
 EmbedBuilder result= new EmbedBuilder();
                result.setTitle("Here's a cat!");
                result.setImage("https://thecatapi.com/v1/images");
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(result.build()).queue();
```

the code above but it just sends the same image again and again

Answer (score 0):

your main problem is you need to use:

```
sendMessageEmbeds()
```

not

```
sendMessage()
```

for my Embeds, I always write my own functions for them here is an example

```
 public static EmbedBuilder exampleEmbed() {
    EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
    builder.setTitle("I am an Embed");
    builder.setDescription("This is for Stack Overflow");
    builder.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

    return builder;
}
```

Then you can call the function an send it:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(exampleEmbed().build()).queue();
```